# Gmail only shows first part of email

Tags: gmail

I have received an email to my Gmail account. When I view it in Gmail in a browser on a desktop PC I only see the short first two paragraphs of the email, with no indication that this is only part of the email, and no way to expand to see the full email. When I view inside the Gmail iOS app, I see the complete email fine.

The content of the email is simple. It is about 400 words of text in a few paragraphs, followed by a large number of blank lines. All line endings are CRLF.

Looking at "Show original", I see it contains a Base64 encoded text/plain blob and a Base64 encoded text/HTML blob. Both blobs decoded contain the same email. The user agent string in the email is `Microsoft-MacOutlook/f.21.0.170409`.

Is there a reason this might be happening?

Does this sound like a known bug in Gmail?

Comment: Eleven, plus some lines with just a few words on.

Comment: No, but that suggestion leads me to a plausible explanation. I can see that some system might think the prose is code (it uses "~" for "approximately" and stuff like that) and decide to block it.